# Is it possible to give the RDC server more CPU priority?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, cpu-usage, priority

I use a Windows Server 2003 machine for some CPU-intensive tasks. I'm wondering, is there any way of giving the Remote Desktop Connection server more priority, so that it doesn't hang while the server is performing CPU-intensive tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set priorities for processes in the [task manager](http://malektips.com/windows-7-process-priority-realtime-high-normal-low.html) or the [command line](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191771). This works in all versions of windows since at least XP.

Higher priority will give more clock cycles to an application, while lower means less. Give your CPU intensive application a lower priority, so it will work normally when nothing else is going on, but will consume less cycles when their are active RDP sessions. If you were to raise the priority of your RDP sessions, you could potentially slow the rest of the system down, which wouldn't make your RDP sessions any faster. Plus, I think I remember the priority of Windows services can't be changed.

Comment: by the way, what is the name of the rdp process/service from the command line? (services can be managed from command line too with some seemingly random name)